# Using BSON as configuration files

Tags: bson

I have some questions about BSON and first I want to understand correctly some things about it.

1. I have seen cases of programs where JSON files were used as configuration files. This is what I would like to attempt. The fact is that .INIs for example are not suited for my use. I must input in my program through a parser a list of parameters. Some are ASCII strings, some are arrays of ASCII strings, some are 32 bit integers, some 64 bit, doubles, arrays of doubles, etc.
   I have read some BSON documentation. But before continuing. I Wonder... is BSON suitable for this use?
2. Say I have an array of strings [ "hello", "meow", "whatsup" ], for example... Are there functions to access specifically each element of the array e.g. similar to array[1] in C for example.
3. It seems the BSON Library documentation contains an API to create BSON objects and all, but I do not see any parser. The point of using BSON is not to implement a parser in my case. So I wonder... is there a Library to parse BSON files, so I only have to access the objects without dealing with parsing?
4. Is the BSON Library disponible on Windows? Can I include it in a C++ MSVC project? I would like to statically link it since my program must be only a .DLL, is it possible?
5. I see that BSON contains data types like int32 and int64. In a BSON file, how can I declarate an instance to be int32?
   Something like this? :

   { "variable" : (int32) 82730 }

Thank you!

Thanks!

Comment: This question can be closed for multiple reasons.

Comment: Which are? I'm seeking informations, I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: 1) Too broad 2) Opinion-based 3) Request for external libraries (see the FAQ) - there are better places to seek the individual pieces of information asked.

Comment: Wait. There's only one Library for BSON actually, the driver provided by MongoDB. I don't ask for external libs. I ask for an implementation of a parser Inside the defacto library, just as if I was asking for some functionalities in the defacto implementation of python for example. Anyways... if it get closed, then I guess I cannot really help it. But honestly, after a good research on the net, I don't find answers to these questions. So be it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. BSON is *not* suitable, because it is a *binary* format. Configuration file stored in BSON will not be human-readable.
   You can, however, use the C++ [BSONObj](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/2.7.0/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_obj.html) to work with a configuration stored in JSON. I rather like that option, I'm using BSON to work with JSON, although I had to rewrite the JSON parser and emitter because the ones MongoDB provide have some limitations (can't parse top-level arrays, 64-bit integers are encoded in a way specific to MongoDB).
2. That depends on the library, there are several BSON libraries: the C++ BSON library, the Java BSON library, the PHP BSON library and so on. I'm only familiar with the C++ BSON library. In that library there is an `operator[] (int field)` in [BSONArray](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/structmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_array.html) so yes, you can do the random access.
   You can also get a `vector` copy of the array and you can get an iterator. The `vector` obviously has the random access and it's trivial to move the iterator to the needed position as well.
3. That's the beauty of it, BSON doesn't need a parser. You can `mmap` a huge BSON file and start using it without any parsing, for example.
4. A large part of the library is header-only, you might have luck using the header-only part of the library without any linking. Compiling and linking the MongoDB DLL should be possible, but I've never tried it.
5. BSON file is binary, it's not human-readable.
   If you're parsing JSON into BSON then the MongoDB JSON parser supports the `"variable" : { "$numberLong" : "82730" }` notation. By default a number is parsed as int32 if it fits and as int64 if not.